# Does Improved Precise Shot negate the need for the the Sniper's Eye rogue talent concerning sneak attack and concealment?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, rogue, sneak-attack

Since *Improved Precise Shot* allows your ranged attacks to ignore any concealment less than total concealment, does a creature with *Sneak Attack* and *Improved Precise Shot* have any need for the *Sniper's Eye* rogue talent in order to inflict *Sneak Attack* on an opponent with partial concealment? Is there any benefit to having both *Sniper's Eye* and *Improved Precise Shot*?

---

[**Improved Precise Shot**](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-precise-shot-combat---final)

> Your ranged attacks ignore anything but total concealment and cover.
>
> **Prerequisites:** Dex 19, Point-Blank Shot, Precise Shot, base attack bonus +11.
>
> **Benefit:** Your ranged attacks ignore the AC bonus granted to targets by anything less than total cover, and the miss chance granted to targets by anything less than total concealment. Total cover and total concealment provide their normal benefits against your ranged attacks.
>
> **Normal:** See the normal rules on the effects of cover and concealment in Combat.

[**Sniper’s Eye**](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo---rogue-talents/sniper-s-eye-ex)

> **Benefit:** A rogue with this talent can apply her sneak attack damage on ranged attacks targeting foes within 30 feet that benefit from concealment. Foes with total concealment are still immune.

[**Sneak Attack**](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue#TOC-Sneak-Attack)

> The rogue must be able to see the target well enough to pick out a vital spot and must be able to reach such a spot. A rogue cannot sneak attack while striking a creature with concealment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even if the [rogue](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue) has the feat [Improved Precise Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-precise-shot-combat---final), the rogue's foe can still have [concealment](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Concealment). If the concealment's less than total, the rogue *will* ignore the miss chance, but the foe'll still *have* the concealment, so the rogue won't deal [sneak attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue#TOC-Sneak-Attack) damage. The feat Improved Precise Shot doesn't make the concealment dissipate; instead, the feat only mitigates its effects for the rogue.

Likewise, even if the rogue has the [rogue talent](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue#TOC-Rogue-Talents) [sniper's eye](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo---rogue-talents/sniper-s-eye-ex), the rogue's foe can still have concealment, but the talent allows the rogue to deal sneak attack damage to the foe if that concealment's less than total. However, the rogue still suffers the miss chance from the foe's concealment.

Having *both* the feat *and* the talent means the rogue, when confronted with a foe with concealment less than total, ignores the miss chance from concealment *and* can deal the foe sneak attack damage.

Comment: It's the text of *Improved Precise Shot* that throws me: "***Your ranged attacks ignore anything but total concealment and cover.***" If you're attacking at range, then you should ignore partial concealment; ergo, if the said ranged attack qualifies for the Sneak Attack feature (by virtue of targeting a flanked or flat-footed opponent), then Sneak Attack damage should apply - with or without the Sniper's Eye talent.

Comment: @Dyndrilliac [Feat Descriptions](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advanced/advancedFeats.html#feat-descriptions) says that the part of the feat you're quoting is "a basic description of what the feat does." However, it's the feat's Benefit that describes "What a feat enables the character ('you' in the feat description) to do." And I totally agree that a feat's basic description should *either* line up with the Benefit *or* be clearly entirely fluff.

Answer (score 0):

*This argues on a strictly 3.5 base. I do not know if PF revised the following point.*

I second Dyndrillac: Negating the miss chance permits sneak attacks. In the spell description of the Assassin 1 spell Critical Strike, published 2006 in Complete Mage (actually an update to the 2005 version in the Spell Compendium) it says:

> **CRITICAL STRIKE**
>
> Divination
>   Level: Assassin 1
>   Components: V, S
>   Casting Time: 1 swift action Range: Personal 
>   Target: You 
>   Duration: One attack
>
> As you complete this spell, you sense the blood rushing through your
>   target's veins
>
> This spell guides your next attack to your foe's vital spots. Your
>   next single attack roll (if it is made before the end of the next
>   round) ignores any miss chance due to concealment. (In the case of a
>   foe that has total concealment, you must still attack the correct
>   square.) This even allows you to deliver a sneak attack against a foe
>   that has concealment.
>
> *Complete Mage, p. 100*

The last sentence is crucial: "*This [i.e. ignoring any miss chance due to concealment] even allows you to deliver a sneak attack against a foe that has concealment."* It does not say "This spell even allows you...". Instead it refers to the fact that the miss chance can be ignored.

Admittedly this is not a premium source for core rules (spell description in an optional rule book), but at least it is official material. So I'd say: Sneak attack on concealed opponents with Improved Precise Shot is RAW - at least as far as D&D v3.5 is concerned.

Comment: Welcome to site. Take the [tour]. Most of the time when a question asks about a system, it's best to answer with information from that system, but *Pathfinder* is billed as compatible with *D&D 3.5*, so that's less of a concern here. However, I do wonder why the antecedent of *This* must be *ignores any miss chance due to concealment* when the description reads like the antecedent of *This* could just as easily be, instead, *This spell*. Anyway, have a good time, and thank you for helping strangers.