# Pathfinder plant domain: Can you really speak with plants?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, cleric, druid

One of my players chose a druid with the domain of plants. The [description says](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/classes/cleric.html#plant-domain):

> You find solace in the green, can grow defensive thorns, and can communicate with plants.

Is this "can communicate with plants" meant literally? Would that be equivalent to the spell [speak with plants](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/speakWithPlants.html#speak-with-plants)? If not how does it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The [Plant](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/plant-domain) domain provides no method of communicating with plants

Some domains include mechanical benefits in their granted powers sections (like the [Travel](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/travel-domain) domain), some domains mandate behaviors or attitudes in their granted powers sections (like the [Law](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/law-domain) domain), and some domains make wild, unsupported claims in their granted powers sections (like that pesky [Plant](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/plant-domain) domain). It's terribly inconsistent, and [you're not the first to notice this particular discrepancy](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2rbql?Plant-Growth).

So, much like picking the Law domain doesn't *actually* mean instantly attaining enlightenment, picking the Plant domain doesn't mean *actually* being able to speak with plants. This happens in *Pathfinder*, where purely descriptive text if taken literally sometimes has no mechanics to support it (like in this [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69112/8610)). Therefore, while it's odd that a cleric with the Plant domain can't speak with plants (and, in fact, typically can't ever cast the spell [*speak with plants*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/speak-with-plants)), unfortunately, that really is the case here.

(Game balance would likely be unaffected were a house rule made allowing a cleric with the Plant domain to use 1/day as a spell-like ability an effect like the spell *speak with plants*. I can say this having played a character in a *D&D 3.5* game with the spell-like ability *speak with plants* 3/day from levels 1 to 9; the campaign remains unbroken by my character's ability to chat with shrubbery. Of course, the campaign doesn't hinge on plant monsters invading the world or some similar plant-themed apocalypse; in that case, such an ability might have more value.)

Comment: I assume the line about communicating with plants probably refers to the *command plants* and *control plants* spells, which involves a bare minimum of "communication" as you tell the plants what you want them to do, and they do it.  I like your house rule, though.

Comment: @gatherer818 Yeah, I *guess* by a strict definition that *is* communication (Sender declares message and receiver interprets message); that's just not what the querent and I were initially thinking of as communication. (As an aside, my favorite alternative method of communication is from the satirical role-playing game *HōL* which has the skill, if I remember correctly, **Telepathy through Pugilism**, allowing a dude to punch someone until that someone understands what he means. More games should have skills like that.)